# How to see output from a php script

Tags: php

I am new to php programming and i have installed it on Ubuntu server, the server is a LAMP server.  As i was doing my introductory lecture, i created first.php file but i understand it cannot be compiled and run like c or java. I would want to know what i must do to see that my program is working. The Ubuntu server that i am working on does not have GUI installed so i would want to know if i can still use it successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you mentioned you dont have a GUI you can try out CLI browsers. many browsers are there among them I always choose lynx and you can install it by using

```
sudo apt-get install lynx-cur
```

make sure that you have placed  your `first.php` file in the proper location.

then check with your .php file.

I mean I have tested it like this

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ lynx 127.0.01
Looking up  '127.0.01' first
```

there 127.0.0.1 indicates the local server.

then it will display output as  [image]

for example if you have written a .php script then you execute it as

php script:

```
root@frank-Jai:~# cat /var/www/ho.php 
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
root@frank-Jai:~#
```

Then I am placing it in the /var/www/ directory with some name. in my case it is po.php . then you cane execute it as

```
lynx 127.0.0.1/ho.php
```

and output will be

[image]

hope that helps you too understand how to execute a php script.

Answer (score 3):

In fairness to the other answers, PHP is *most commonly* hosted on a webserver and run through `mod_php` or `php-cgi` but you can also write command-line and graphical PHP scripts and applications.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
php -f file.php
```

That will run and output the PHP file to the terminal. If you've got a ton of HTML in the php file or it relies on various `$_SERVER` variables, this just isn't going to work. Just Install lamp and work out of `/var/www`:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

<sup>(Note: The `^` is not a mistake — it's how apt-get knows to install a *task*)</sup>

The apache2 version that was published when the Ubuntu 14.04 release was made is 2.4.7 and starting with this version it seems that, for security reasons, the new root directory for the server is:

```
/var/www/html
```

Comment: It worked and i got my output in terminal, My server is already a lamp server ,  i would want to know how i can work out of /var/www

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not need compilation.

The default site is under /var/www

Put your test file there and get access with browser http://example.com/first.php

Also if you want to test directly in console you just write

```
php /path/to/file.php
```